# How to generate a (valid) PDF with "a2ps foo.txt"?

Tags: macos, terminal, pdf, homebrew

I installed `a2ps` on Mac OS X 10.10.4 via brew. My `~/.a2psrc` contains `Options: --medium=Letter -P pdf`. But when I do `a2ps foo.txt` no PDF file is generated (this used to work on Ubuntu/Debian Linux). When I do `a2ps -o foo.pdf foo.txt` I get a PDF, but it cannot be opened (maybe it is corrupted?). However, on `a2ps -o foo.pdf foo.txt` I get a PS which I can then convert to PDF (and open). How can I make `a2ps foo.txt` to produce a valid PDF on Mac OS X? Note that I'm looking specifically for the command line `a2ps`, no GUI or other programs (obviously it's easy to generate a PDF from a text file with other tools)

Comment: Does `man a2ps` or `info a2ps` answer your question?

Comment: @Marius Hofert, Please checkout my updated answer as I've added info for installing `a2pdf` which will create _PDF Documents_ from _Text Documents_ via the Command Line in Terminal.

Comment: @fd0 No, but user3439894 explanation helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `a2ps` utility is for formatting files for printing on a PostScript printer, hence its name is not `a2pdf`.

The file you created under Linux (or OS X), which is a miss-named *.pdf* file, is in fact a *PostScript* file and many Linux Distros will open it anyway.  Thus leading you to believe is was a *PDF Document* when in reality it's not.

Looking at the file created under Linux in a Hex Editor its header starts off with, e.g., `%!PS-Adobe-3.0` and a *PDF Document* starts with, e.g., `%PDF-1.6%`.

This is why you get the "The file “filename.pdf” could not be opened. It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize." error message under OS X when trying to open a *PostScript Document* with a miss-named *PDF Document* extension.

**Update: Installing a2pdf**

After doing a little research I found [`a2pdf`](https://github.com/gitpan/a2pdf).  Further research required having [Font::TTF::Font](http://search.cpan.org/~mhosken/Font-TTF-1.04/lib/Font/TTF/Font.pm) and [PDF::API2](http://search.cpan.org/~ssimms/PDF-API2-2.023/lib/PDF/API2.pm) also installed.  So I downloaded all three packages [master.zip (for a2pdf)](https://github.com/gitpan/a2pdf/archive/master.zip), [Font-TTF-1.04.tar.gz](http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/M/MH/MHOSKEN/Font-TTF-1.04.tar.gz) and [PDF-API2-2.023.tar.gz](http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/S/SS/SSIMMS/PDF-API2-2.023.tar.gz).

Next I extracted all three and installed them in the same manner in the following order, Font::TTF::Font, PDF::API2 then the master.zip (for a2pdf).  I did this in a Terminal using the following commands.

```
$ cd $target_directory
$ perl Makefile.PL
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

I then tested, from my Home Directory, with: `a2pdf filename.txt > filename.pdf`

It create *filename.pdf* and I then opened it in **Preview** just fine as a *PDF Document*.

That said, there are other modules that can be installed to do things like *syntax highlighting*, e.g. [Perl::Tidy](http://search.cpan.org/~shancock/Perl-Tidy-20140711/lib/Perl/Tidy.pod).  So you'll need to do a bit more research to utilize the full capabilities of `a2pdf`.

Note: I have Xcode and Command Line Tools for Xcode installed and as long as you have Command Line Tools for Xcode installed, which is a Homebrew prerequisite, you can install all of this from the Terminal the old fashioned way if not available from Homebrew, which I do not believe it is.

Comment: Thanks, that's very informative. I didn't know that Linux 'tricked' me here...

Answer (score 1):

This can be done as follows:

1. Save text file in UTF-8 encoding, even though `a2ps supports Latin1 only
   (This is done mainly because UTF-8 is standard nowadays.)
2. Convert text file to Latin1, using `recode`
3. Call `a2ps` on the result
4. Convert resulting PS file to PDF, using `ps2pdf` from LaTeX installation
5. Optionally, use `gs` to convert the resulting PDF to PDF-1.3 to reduce its file size
6. Copy the PDF-1.3 back to the directory the text file lives in

In Linux, this can be done by the following script.

The simplest way of calling it is `txt2pdf file.txt`, assuming it is saved under `~/bin/txt2pdf` or some other standard location. It produces `file.txt.pdf`

```
 #!/bin/bash

 maketempdir () {
     local result
     if ! result="$(mktemp -d)"; then
         fail 'Cannot create temp directory'
     fi
     echo "$result"
 }

 trycd () {
     if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
         fail 'trycd needs exactly one argument'
     fi

     if ! cd "$1" ; then
         debugoutput 'tried to cd to '"$(readlink -f "$1")"
         fail 'cannot cd to '"$1"
     fi
 }

 fail () {
     #
     # print an error message, then exit with a code
     #
     # $1: error message
     # $2: exit code
     #
     if [ -z "$1" ]; then fail 'Unspecified error' '1'; fi
     if [ -z "$2" ]; then fail "$1" '1';                fi
     yellow "$(bold "$(printf '\n!!!!! %s\n\n' "$1")")" >&2
     sleep 0.2
     exit "$2"
 }

 yellow() {
     local yellow='\e[0;93m'
     local normal='\e[0m'
     echo -ne "${yellow}"    # echo -n: Kein Zeilenumbruch am Ende
     echo -nE "$@"           # echo -e: Escape-Sequenzen interpretieren
     echo -e "${normal}"     # echo -E: Escape-Sequenzen nicht interpretieren
 }

 # tput zu benutzen wäre nicht schlecht. Damit kriegt man aber nur ein
 # blasses Gelb und kein Kanariengelb hin.
 # Außerdem werden Zeilenumbrüche verschluckt, vermutlich wegen des
 #    echo -nE "$@"

 bold() {
     local bold=$(tput bold)
     local normal=$(tput sgr0) 
     echo -ne "${bold}"        # auf Fettschrift umschalten
     echo -nE "$@"             # Text ausgeben
     echo -e "${normal}"       # auf normale Schrift umschalten
 }

 # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/
 # how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux
 # 2017-01-07

 debugoutput() {
     if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
         fail 'debugoutput needs exactly one argument'
     fi
     printf '%s\n' "$1" >&2
 }


 tempdir="$(maketempdir)"
 readonly tempdir

 wd=$(readlink -e $(pwd))
 readonly wd

 trycd "$dir"
 trycd "$wd"

 orientation=null
 verbose=null

 case "$#" in

     1)
         exec "$0" --portrait "$1"
         ;;

     2)
         ## 1. Fall: "$1" ist --verbose, "$2" ist die Eingabedatei
         ## 2. Fall: "$1" ist die Ausrichtung, "$2" ist die Eingabedatei

         case "$1" in

             --verbose)
                 orientation='--portrait'
                 verbose=true
                 ;;
             --portrait|--landscape)
                 orientation="$1"
                 verbose=false
                 ;;
             *)
                 fail 'Erster Parameter muss Ausrichtung angeben oder --verbose lauten'
                 ;;
         esac
         infile="$2"
         ;;

     3)

         case "$1" in

             --portrait|--landscape)
                 orientation="$1"
                 ;;
             *)
                 fail 'Erster Parameter muss Ausrichtung angeben'
                 ;;
         esac

         case "$2" in            
             --verbose)
                 orientation="$1"
                 verbose=true
                 ;;
             *)
                 fail 'Zweiter Parameter muss --verbose lauten'
                 ;;
         esac

         infile="$(readlink -e "$3")"

         if [ -z "$infile" ]; then
             fail 'Eingabedatei '"$3"' existiert nicht'
         fi

         if [ ! -f "$infile" ]; then
             fail 'Eingabedatei '"$infile"' existiert nicht'
         fi
         ;;

     *)
         cat <<EOF
 Usage: $0 dateiname
 Usage: $0 [--portrait | --landscape] dateiname
 Usage: $0 --verbose dateiname
 Usage: $0 [--portrait | --landscape] --verbose dateiname
 EOF
         exit 1
         ;;
 esac

 readonly infile
 # readonly orientation # später
 readonly verbose
 # echo 'orientation='"$orientation"
 # echo 'verbose='"$verbose"
 # echo 'infile='"$infile"

 ###### 1. Schritt: Eingabedatei nach latin1 konvertieren

 bn=$(basename "$infile")
 tempfilename="$tempdir"'/'"$bn"'.txt' # will be latin1 after recode
 if ! cp -a "$infile" "$tempfilename"; then
     fail 'Cannot copy '"$bn"' to tempdir'
 fi

 if ! recode UTF-8..Latin1 "$tempfilename"; then
     fail 'Cannot recode '"$tempfilename"' from UTF-8 to Latin1' 
 fi

 psout="${tempfilename%.*}"'.ps'

 ###### 2. Schritt: a2ps aufrufen

 case "$orientation" in

     --portrait)
         a2ps -q -Eplain -R --encoding=latin1 --columns=1 -l 85 -o "$psout" "$tempfilename"
         ;;

     --landscape)
         a2ps -q -Eplain -r --encoding=latin1 --columns=1 -l 115 -o "$psout" "$tempfilename"
         ;;

 esac

 ###### 3. Schritt: ps nach PDF konvertieren

 pdfout="${psout/.ps/.pdf}"

 if ! ps2pdf "$psout" "$pdfout"; then
     fail 'Konnte PS nicht nach PDF konvertieren'
 fi

 ###### 4. Schritt: Erzeugte PDF-Datei so klein wie möglich machen

 smallout="${pdfout/.pdf/.small.pdf}"
 out="${smallout/.small/}"

 if ! gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.3 -dNOPAUSE\
      -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile="$smallout" "$pdfout"
 then
     fail 'Konnte PDF-Datei nicht verkleinern'
 fi

 if ! mv -f "$smallout" "$out"; then
     fail 'Konnte Ausgabedatei nicht erstellen'
 fi

 ###### 5. Schritt: PDF in das Verzeichnis kopieren, in dem die Eingabedatei liegt

 if ! cp -a "$out" "$wd"; then
     fail 'Konnte Ausgabedatei nicht in Eingabeverzeichnis schreiben'
 fi

 if [ "$verbose" = 'true' ]; then
     echo "$wd"/"$(basename "$out")"
 fi

 if ! rm -rf "$tempdir"; then
     fail 'Konnte temporäres Verzeichnis nicht löschen'
 fi
```